# How to convert the response got from a server from string to array in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here I got the response after posting parameters successfully and I need to retrieve it back but the problem I got stuck here that I had saved the data in `responseString` and it is storing in the form of string and when I try to retrieve it and saving in an array unable to save can anyone help me how to save and the data is in below format

Here is the server response

```
[
  {
    "carrier_code": "flatrate",
    "method_code": "flatrate",
    "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
    "method_title": "Fixed",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  },
  {
    "carrier_code": "tablerate",
    "method_code": "bestway",
    "carrier_title": "Best Way",
    "method_title": "Table Rate",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  }
]
```

Here is the json function to post parameters

```
        func shippingmethodURL(shippingMethodAPI:String) {
        let url = NSURL(string: shippingMethodAPI)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        print(shippingMethodAPI)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addtoCartVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "checkout") as! CheckoutViewController
        let parameters : [String: Any] = ["address":
            [ "region": "California",
                "region_code": "CA",
                "region_id": "12",
                "country_id": "US",
                "company": "Test",
                "telephone": "9492162752",
                "postcode": "43",
                "city": "Chennai",
                "firstname": "gdfgdgdfg",
                "lastname": "dgdfgdfgg",
                "email": "sfdsfsdf@gmail.com",
                "prefix": "",
                "sameAsBilling": 1,
                "street": ["Dsfdsfsd dfdsfdsf dsfsfdsfsf sdfsfdsfsdfC"]]]
        print(parameters)
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        print(request)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

            let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            self.keyStatusCode = status
            print(status)
            let array = responseString
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: you need to have a model class , and then have an array of that model class. Now you can save fetched objects in array .

Comment: how to connect output server data to model class ? @TusharSharma

Comment: Unrelated but the server doesn't have a sense of aesthetics. It doesn't care about *pretty printed* text at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting `Data` to `String` However it is `Array` You need to use `JSONSerialization` class to achive this

You have to replace this code

```
 let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

with

```
let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String : Any]]
```

**EDIT**

You need put it in `do try catch` block like this

```
   do {
        let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String : Any]]

    } catch {
        print("Exception occured \(error))")
    }
```

Comment: You need to put it in do try catch block

Comment: thanks working if I need to retrieve the data then I need to create model class for it @Jon Snow

Comment: If you use Alamofire Object Mapper (Third party library) it will do automatically for you , You can create object mapper class using `SwiftyJSONAccelerator` (Mac app)

Comment: @LeoDabus Edited answer

Comment: Note that adding localizedDescription is redundant. `print("json error:", error)`